# Export our PnP variables and outcomes to CSV file

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell, pnp

I have this script to loop through all site collections >> and all document libraries  >> then list the folders in this format "Site Name >> List Name >> Folder Name":-

```
$AdminUrl = "https://*****-admin.sharepoint.com/"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminUrl -Interactive 
 
#sharepoint online get all site collections PowerShell
$SiteColl = Get-PnPTenantSite
 
 
#sharepoint online PowerShell iterate through all site collections
ForEach($Site in $SiteColl)
{
 
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Interactive
   $Webs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb
               
               
    #Get All document libraries
ForEach($Web in $Webs)
    {
               $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList -Web $Web | Where-Object {$_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false}
    #Iterate through each document library
    ForEach($Library in $DocumentLibraries)
               {
               $f =   Get-PnPFolder -List $Library
               
               ForEach($folder in $f)
               {
               
               Write-Host $Site.Title " --> "  $Library.Title  " --> " $folder.Name
               }
               
               }
}
 
 
}
```

but i need to export all the   `Write-Host $Site.Title " --> "  $Library.Title  " --> " $folder.Name` into CSV file instead of printing them inside the host.. any advice?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use below code to export necessary information to CSV file:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminUrl -Interactive 
 
#sharepoint online get all site collections PowerShell
$SiteColl = Get-PnPTenantSite
$csvOutput = @()

#sharepoint online PowerShell iterate through all site collections
ForEach ($Site in $SiteColl) {
 
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Site.Url -Interactive
    $Webs = Get-PnPSubWeb -Recurse -IncludeRootWeb               
               
    #Get All document libraries
    ForEach ($Web in $Webs) {
        $DocumentLibraries = Get-PnPList -Web $Web | Where-Object { $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $_.Title -ne "Site Assets" -and $_.Hidden -eq $false }
        #Iterate through each document library
        ForEach ($Library in $DocumentLibraries) {
            $f = Get-PnPFolder -List $Library
        
            ForEach ($folder in $f) {
                Write-Host $Site.Title " --> "  $Library.Title  " --> " $folder.Name
                $csvOutput += New-Object PsObject -property @{'Site' = $Site.Title; 'Library' = $Library.Title; 'Folder' = $folder.Name}
            }
        }
    }
}
$csvOutput | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "C:\users\myuser\desktop\export.csv"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. this will create a single column inside the csv,, can i have 3 columns instead (Site.Title | Library.Title | Folder.NAme)?

Comment: @Gamesh Sanap also i tried your code an it only return numbers inside the csv

Comment: Try updated code above using: `$csvOutput += New-Object PsObject -property @{'Site' = $Site.Title; 'Library' = $Library.Title; 'Folder' = $folder.Name}`